# Pandas: full outer join with filled-in blanks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have the following df:

| Date | Product | Region | MTD PnL | FYTD PnL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | Northeast | $300 | $15,000 |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | Southeast | $200 | $10,000 |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | Mid-Atlantic | $375 | $12,000 |
| 21/6/1 | Pepsi | Northeast | $150 | $7,000 |
| 21/6/1 | Pepsi | Southwest | $70 | $4,000 |

And I have a separate, exhaustive list of Regions:

| Region |
| --- |
| Northeast |
| Southeast |
| Mid-Atlantic |
| Midwest |
| Prairies |
| Southwest |
| Northwest |
| California |

I need to join this list to the df so that for each given product, all of the regions are shown (with zeroes in the PnL columns if no values are present)

So far I have used `pd.merge`  to (full outer) join the df and region list and I got the following output:

| Date | Product | Region | MTD PnL | FYTD PnL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | Northeast | $300 | $15,000 |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | Southeast | $200 | $10,000 |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | Mid-Atlantic | $375 | $12,000 |
| 21/6/1 |  | Midwest | NaN | NaN |
| 21/6/1 |  | Prairies | NaN | NaN |
| 21/6/1 |  | Southwest | NaN | NaN |
| 21/6/1 |  | Northwest | NaN | NaN |
| 21/6/1 |  | California | NaN | NaN |
| 21/6/1 | Pepsi | Northeast | $150 | $7,000 |
| 21/6/1 |  | Southeast | NaN | NaN |
| 21/6/1 |  | Mid-Atlantic | NaN | NaN |
| 21/6/1 |  | Midwest | NaN | NaN |
| 21/6/1 |  | Prairies | NaN | NaN |
| 21/6/1 | Pepsi | Southwest | $70 | $4,000 |
| 21/6/1 |  | Northwest | NaN | NaN |
| 21/6/1 |  | California | NaN | NaN |

But I need the Product column to list the product in every row, as well as the two PnL columns to show $0 instead of NaN.  Like this:

| Date | Product | Region | MTD PnL | FYTD PnL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | Northeast | $300 | $15,000 |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | Southeast | $200 | $10,000 |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | Mid-Atlantic | $375 | $12,000 |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | Midwest | $0 | $0 |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | Prairies | $0 | $0 |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | Southwest | $0 | $0 |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | Northwest | $0 | $0 |
| 21/6/1 | Coke | California | $0 | $0 |
| 21/6/1 | Pepsi | Northeast | $150 | $7,000 |
| 21/6/1 | Pepsi | Southeast | $0 | $0 |
| 21/6/1 | Pepsi | Mid-Atlantic | $0 | $0 |
| 21/6/1 | Pepsi | Midwest | $0 | $0 |
| 21/6/1 | Pepsi | Prairies | $0 | $0 |
| 21/6/1 | Pepsi | Southwest | $70 | $4,000 |
| 21/6/1 | Pepsi | Northwest | $0 | $0 |
| 21/6/1 | Pepsi | California | $0 | $0 |

So far I used `.fillna(0)` to replace the NaNs but I cannot find a way to fill in the products names in a programmatic way.  What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.reindex` with the product of all the unique values for the other levels -- that way the values for the basis are filled in. `.reindex` also supports a `fill_value` for non-Index columns.

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.Date.unique(), df1.Product.unique(), df2.Region.unique()],
                                 names=['Date', 'Product', 'Region'])

df1 = (df1.set_index(['Date', 'Product', 'Region'])
          .reindex(idx, fill_value='$0')
          .reset_index())
```

---

```
      Date Product        Region MTD PnL FYTD PnL
0   21/6/1    Coke     Northeast    $300  $15,000
1   21/6/1    Coke     Southeast    $200  $10,000
2   21/6/1    Coke  Mid-Atlantic    $375  $12,000
3   21/6/1    Coke       Midwest      $0       $0
4   21/6/1    Coke      Prairies      $0       $0
5   21/6/1    Coke     Southwest      $0       $0
6   21/6/1    Coke     Northwest      $0       $0
7   21/6/1    Coke    California      $0       $0
8   21/6/1   Pepsi     Northeast    $150   $7,000
9   21/6/1   Pepsi     Southeast      $0       $0
10  21/6/1   Pepsi  Mid-Atlantic      $0       $0
11  21/6/1   Pepsi       Midwest      $0       $0
12  21/6/1   Pepsi      Prairies      $0       $0
13  21/6/1   Pepsi     Southwest     $70   $4,000
14  21/6/1   Pepsi     Northwest      $0       $0
15  21/6/1   Pepsi    California      $0       $0
```